# Probability of getting a particular sum from n m-sided dice c#

Tags: c#, math, probability

I am trying to generate a probability of getting a specific number from n dice, with no guarantee of them having the same number of sides. (eg, 1d6 + 2d10)

I know there is a really expensive way of doing it (With recursion), but if there is a mathematical way of determining the chance of an event happening, that would be way better.

Comment: You might have better luck at [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: or maybe [stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @JSteward Programmers say it is a math problem.  Mathematicians say that it is a programming problem.  Anyone with a CS background should instantly recognize it as a dynamic programming problem and know how to solve it with a computer.

Comment: @btilly > 30 years CS experience. No idea what 'dynamic programming problem is', and my first reaction would be 'look up the maths'

Comment: @pm100 By CS experience do you mean time spent programming?  Or time spent in academia?  It doesn't matter.  DP problems are standard fare for CS interviews, coding challenges, and the like.  Basically DP means that you save intermediate calculations into a lookup table so that you don't have to repeat the calculation.  There are two basic approaches.  Bottom up means that you're building the lookup table from the most basic to the most complex.  (Which lets you throw away parts that are no longer needed.)  Top down means that you write a recursive solution then memoize.

Comment: Classic examples include Knuth's line break algorithm, the longest common subsequence problem, and the egg dropping problem.

Comment: The sum of independent variables has a distribution given by the convolution of the distributions of the variables. For discrete distributions, the convolution is easily stated as a simple summation. A faster and only slightly more complex approach is to take the fast Fourier transform of the distributions, multiply them, then take the inverse FFT. That works because FFT(conv(x, y)) = FFT(x) times FFT(y). Incidentally I think this question is probably a duplicate -- I'm pretty sure I've seen dice questions posted before; searching SO might find some.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this:

- Create an output array `count` with length sum(sides all dice)+1, i.e. so that the max that can possibly be rolled works as an index.
- This represents the number of ways that the index can be rolled. Initialise this with [0] = 1.
- For each dice of N sides, enumerate the results of each possible rolled value.

  - Copy the existing count array into prev, say, and create a new empty count array
  - for roll = 1 to N, for total = 0 to count.length-1-roll, count[total+roll]+=prev[total]
- Now the probability of rolling value = count[value] / sum(count)

Notes:

- This isn't, as you feared, either really expensive or needs recursion. This will be O(N^2) where N as the total faces on all dice.
- This will compute the probability of all outputs not just the one output that you're interested in, which may be an issue if the total faces is extremely large and the value you're interested in small. You could cap the count array at length (value you're interested in) + 1, if necessary, and compute the total number of rolls as the product of each die face as you process it rather than from sum(count) as I've suggested above.

Comment: Good answer (+1). Unless `n` is in the hundreds or even thousands (or the number of faces is large), explicit probability calculation should be very quick.

Answer (score 0):

@Rup already gave one standard solution, the bottom up dynamic programming method.

The top down approach is to write your recursive function..and then [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) it.  That is when your function is called you first check whether you have seen this before (ie you look into a dictionary to see if you have a "memo" to yourself about the answer), and if you haven't you calculate the answer and save it.  Then you return the memoized answer.

The usual tradeoffs apply:

1. Top down is easier to figure out and write.
2. Bottom up lets you see that you don't need to store 2 dice answers when you have the 3 dice ones, and therefore reduces working memory requirements.

Therefore it is good to know both approaches, but I always reach for a top down approach first.

Answer (score -1):

Here I generated from 2 dice rolling

1 Randon() will be generated from n faces

2 here n times is rolled on

3 sum is displayed for n rolled

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dicerolling
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Random x = new Random();
            int throw_times = 1;
            int sum = 0;
            int[] dice = new int[2];
            dice[0] = x.Next(1, 7);
            dice[1] = x.Next(1, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("enter the no of rollings :");
            var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                dice[0] = x.Next(1, 7);
                dice[1] = x.Next(1, 7);

                int total_var = dice[0] + dice[1];
                sum +=  dice[0] + dice[1] ;//total in array

                Console.Write("Throw " + throw_times + ": " + dice[0] + " d " + dice[1] + " = ");
                Console.WriteLine(total_var);
                throw_times++;

                Array.Sort(dice);

                for (int a = dice.Length - 1; a >= 0; a--)
                {
                    int s = dice[a];
                    Console.WriteLine("#" + s);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Total sum: " + sum);//only returns sum of last 2 rolls


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will estimate the answer yes, but for six sided dice only. But the probability should be easily computable too without having to resort to random sampling.

Comment: just change  dice[0] = x.Next(1, 10);
                dice[1] = x.Next(1, 10);

Comment: dice[0] = x.Next(1, 20);
                dice[1] = x.Next(1, 20); here sesond parameter can take dynamicaly to change the sides

Comment: hi Rup is there any dout for changing the sides

Comment: No, you're right, that is easy to do. But the other bit was my main point: it should be easy enough to compute the probability rather than sample it.

Comment: The question is to compute the probability that the total sum of our dice is a given value, e.g. you would expect 2D6 to total 7 with probability 1/6. One way to compute this is to roll 2D6 a large number of times and to count how many times we get a 7 which will get us an approximate answer only. However these are small integers, so it's easy enough to instead count the number of combinations that total 7, which is 6, out of 36 possible rolls, and get 1/6 exactly. So this problem can be solved accurately without using random numbers at all.

Comment: @Rup You mean here use the mathmatics

Comment: @Dominic are u gain something from this answer